# What is the native structure of amyloid-beta protein under physiological conditions?

Tags: biophysics, protein-structure

The amyloid-beta protein forms cross-beta structured fibrils. But under normal physiological conditions what is their predominant secondary structure. Is it alpha-helix, random coil or beta-sheet?

Comment: What research have you done yourself to answer this question?  There are many sources of information on this topic if you search the Internet. Tell us what you have found and why it doesn’t answer your question. See the Help on asking questions.